# Specify AD groups in ADImportService for Kentico

Tags: active-directory, kentico

I'm trying to import specific users by groups in the ADImportService in Kentico (not to be confused with the ADImport utility). Unfortunately, neither the documentation nor the open source code shows (at least to me) that it has the capability to do this. Is there some configuration setting I'm missing that allows me to do this? If not, is there an alternative solution?

ADImportService: https://github.com/Kentico/ADImportService

AD Import Utility: https://github.com/Kentico/ADImport

Answer (score 0):

In kentico 8.0 this is how AD import performed hopefully it will help you out in configuration/ settings.Kinldy take a look.

[Select users & groups to be imported](https://docs.kentico.com/k8/external-utilities/kentico-ad-import-utility/importing-users-and-roles-from-active-directory#ImportingusersandrolesfromActiveDirectory-Step6%E2%80%93Selectusers&groupstobeimported)